# laravel command not found error in git

Tags: git, laravel, homestead

I want to create a project from git. Homestead and Vagrant installation is completely done. But in git, When i run laravel new deepdivecms it says laravel command not found.

If i say $echo $PATH it says

```
**/c/Users/Cagri/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Cagri/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/xampp/php:/c/composer:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/cmd:/c/Users/Cagri/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/c/Users/Cagri/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/Cagri/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code Insiders/bin:/c/Users/Cagri/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl**
```

Can you please help me about what to do? Thanks...

Comment: Adding a "solved" comment is extremely counterproductive. Please either [post an answer explaining the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so you can help other users or delete your question.

Comment: Thank u sir for this information..

Answer (score 0):

In a regular CMD session (where laravel would be recognized), type:

```
where laravel
```

Then make sure in your bash session, that same folder is present (or add it to your PATH in your `~/.bashrc`)